# SQL Select invoice data, group by date and order by highest sales

Tags: sql, function, date, join, group-by

I am trying to put together an SQL statement which should give me one row for each week of the year, containing the total amount of invoices from that week as well as the sum of all prices.

The invoice data is stored in 2 tables: 1 for the invoices and 1 for the data for each single invoice. It kinda looks like this (simplified):

Invoices:

```
Id | inv_date   |
---+------------|
11 | 2021-03-01 |
12 | 2021-03-01 |
13 | 2021-03-01 |
14 | 2021-03-02 |
...
```

Invoice positions:

```
Invoice_Id | position | article_no | amount | price  |
-----------+----------+------------+--------+--------|
11         | 1        | 12345      | 1      |  12.95 |
12         | 1        | 23456      | 1      |  22.99 |
12         | 2        | 23457      | 5      |   3.95 |
13         | 1        | 12345      | 2      |  12.95 |
14         | 1        | 98765      | 1      | 199.95 |
...
```

So what I'm aiming for would look something like this:

```
year | week | amount_invoices | sales_total|
-----+------+-----------------+------------|
2020 | 51   | 100             | 4500.91    |
2020 | 52   |  90             | 4200.50    |
2020 | 53   |  85             | 4155.55    |
2021 |  1   |  88             | 4280.81    |
2021 |  2   | 105             | 4812.85    |
2021 |  3   | 112             | 4722.94    |
...
```

I am no SQL expert so all I cound piece together so far is getting a list of all the years and each individual week. I also tried including the amount of invoices and the total sales but those 2 columns return false values the way I'm doing it... the amount of invoices is way too hight and the sales are off too.
my current SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, i.inv_date) as year,
    DATEPART(week, i.inv_date) as week,
    COUNT(i.id) as amount_invoices,
    SUM(p.price) as sales_total
FROM
    invoices i
JOIN
    invoice_positions p ON i.id = p.invoice_id 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(week, i.inv_date), DATEPART(year, i.inv_date)
ORDER BY
    year DESC, week DESC
```

if someone could point me into the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Tag your question with the datab se you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of invoices is off because you are joining to the pieces part, so the `COUNT()` is really counting the pieces.

The total amount on the other hand should be correct, based on the information in the question.  You can first the first problem using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, i.inv_date) as year,
       DATEPART(week, i.inv_date) as week,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) as amount_invoices,
       SUM(p.price) as sales_total
FROM invoices i JOIN
     invoice_positions p
     ON i.id = p.invoice_id 
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, i.inv_date), DATEPART(year, i.inv_date)
ORDER BY year DESC, week DESC;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was close then I guess. The total amount was correct after all but I mixed up the rows when I compared it to the results I had at hand already. DISTINCT does the trick then, thank you.